# Cast using Reflection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I've created a generic function as below (just a s a proof) that will take a `List<T>` collection and reverse it, returning a new `List<T>` as its output.

```
public static List<T> ReverseList<T>(List<T> sourceList)
{
    T[] outputArray = new T[sourceList.Count];
    sourceList.CopyTo(outputArray);
    return outputArray.Reverse().ToList();
}
```

The purpose of the proof is that I only know what `T` is at runtime.  I am therefore using reflection to call the above method as follows:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // As an example, but could be any type for T

MethodInfo myMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("ReverseList");
MethodInfo resultMethod = myMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(int) });
object result = resultMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { myList });
```

There are two problems here:

1. In the second line, rather than supplying `typeof(int)`, I would like suppliy somthign akin to `myList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetType()` in order to make things more flexible because I do not know `T` until runtime.  Doing this results in a runtime error when the Invoke runs as follows: "Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Int32]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.RuntimeType]'."
2. The result of the `Invoke()` method returns an object.  When debugging, I can see that the object is of type List, but attempting to use it tells me that I have an invalid cast.  I assume that I need to use reflection to box the result in to the correct type (i.e. in this example, the equivalent of `(result as List<int>`).

Does anyone have any pointers that could help me resolve this?  Apologies if this is not to clear, I can probably provide more detail if asked.

TIA

Comment: Wait... so why don't you just say `myList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetType()`?

Comment: Is the code in the second box intended to be inside a generic function, or are you planning to actually pass around an instance of Type?

Comment: Ah, because that results in the exception as follows: `"Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.RuntimeType]'."`

Comment: @siride no The code in the second box is calling the generic method using reflection.  Line 3 is about to be corrected as @Ben Voigt has an answer for that part.

Comment: @mnield well then I fail to see what the problem is.  You already know the type of the list, which is `int`.  No need for reflection solutions.

Comment: @siried Acutally there is, `int` is only there to prove the method invocation using reflection.  In reality it could be any one a a vast number of classes inherited in another Library that I have limited control over.  It could be a class representing an investment strategy, a member of staff, a domicile code (and so the list goes on).  Passing all of that in to the generic method is required at runtime unless I want to spend a week writing switch statements.  Where the next problem lies is casting the result of the invoke back to the same collection type so that it can be used.

Comment: @mnield you didn't make it clear where that code lives, which is why I asked my first question.

Comment: I can't for the life of me fathom how you could have a list of something and not be able to use generics from bottom to top.  I think you need to rethink why you need to do the code in part II.

Comment: @siride Sorry, I though I had made it clear in my second paragraph that the second code block was used to call the generic method.  As I say, I have to do it this way (I have tried others) as I do not know `T` until runtime.  There is no common base class or inteface for the classes of type `T`, they are just there and I cannot change that.  If you know of a way to call a method where the type is unknown at runtime without reflecting the type, I genuinely would appreciate knowing what it is.

Comment: If there is no common base type, then just use an unconstrained generic parameter.  Don't use reflection when you don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The result of the Invoke() method
>   returns an object. When debugging, I
>   can see that the object is of type
>   List, but attempting to use it tells
>   me that I have an invalid cast. I
>   assume that I need to use reflection
>   to box the result in to the correct
>   type (i.e. in this example, the
>   equivalent of (result as List).

The only workaround for this is I can think of is to pass an empty list as the second parameter of the method and to populate that list - the reference returned by `Invoke()` will **always** be only of type object, but inside the generic method you do have access to the type itself:

```
List<int> reverseList = new List<int>();
resultMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { myList, reverseList });
```

...

```
public static void ReverseList<T>(List<T> sourceList, List<T> resultList)
{
    T[] outputArray = new T[sourceList.Count];
    sourceList.CopyTo(outputArray);
    resultList.AddRange(outputArray.Reverse());
}
```

Comment: That's a blindingly simple approach.  I think this may be a "Can't see the wood for the trees" moment. :)

Answer (score 5):

You've got one `GetType()` too many.  Happens to everyone.

`myList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]` IS a `System.Type` -- the one you're looking for.

`myList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetType()` is a `System.Type` describing `System.Type` (well, actually the concrete subclass `System.RuntimeType`).

---

Also, your `ReverseList` function is serious overkill.  It does an extra copy just to avoid calling `List.Reverse`.  There's a better way to circumvent that:

```
public static List<T> ReverseList<T>(List<T> sourceList)
{
    return Enumerable.Reverse(sourceList).ToList();
}
```

or

```
public static List<T> ReverseList<T>(List<T> sourceList)
{
    var result = new List<T>(sourceList);
    result.Reverse();
    return result;
}
```

or

```
public static List<T> ReverseList<T>(List<T> sourceList)
{
    var result = new List<T>();
    result.Capacity = sourceList.Count;
    int i = sourceList.Count;
    while (i > 0)
        result.Add(sourceList[--i]);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar!  That's exactly what I've done there.  +1 for fixing the first problem.

Comment: As an aside, yes the method was overkill.  It's not really the method that I was bothered about, but the way in which it was called and the result dealt with.  In reality `ReverseList<T>` could have just returned the same list as far as this demo is concerned.

Answer (score 3):

To access it as a `List<T>`, yes you'd need to find T using reflection (probably over the interfaces, for example `typeof(IList<>)`, and use more reflection and MakeGenericMethod etc. In all honesty, it isn't worth it: you would do better to check for the non-generic `IList`:

```
var list = result as IList;
if (list != null)
{
    // loop over list etc
}
```

Generics ad reflection are not good friends.

Note in 4.0 there are also some tricks you can do here with `dynamic` and generics.

Comment: OK, maybe I'm being a little dim.  I can find the type of T just fine, what I am having trouble doing is casting it so that I can assign it to things.  I.e. `List<int> jeffTheVariable = result;` will not compile as I cannot implicitly cast Object to List<int>.  I appreciate Generics and Reflection don't get on too well, but the library in my target application has a large number of classes that I really need to automate.

Comment: Generics and reflection get along just fine in my experience, if you have some sample code to look at and serious attention to detail.  Of course, you've done some really tricksy stuff with them, so you ought to know better than I do, but I think you may be biased because of the really hard problems you've attacked.

Comment: Biased, me... yeah - probably :)  The bit that gets me is that it's real easy to get 90% of the way and the last 10% always has me scratching my head/pulling my hair out.

Comment: @Ben other way around - having used them much, I think **in many cases** this approach is overkill; just going non-generic works fine for 95%+ of such cases, and is simpler to get right.